# Pandas Dataframe Removing New Line Feeds

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data:

```
          all_data
0     \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n
1      \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n
```

How can I remove the `'\n`' characters?

I have tried the following:

```
df.replace(r'\\n','',regex=True)
df = df.replace(r'\\n','',regex=True)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 1 or more regex expression.

```
df.replace(r'\\n+', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
  all_data
0         
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
In [3067]: df['all_data'].str.replace(r'\\n','',regex=True) 
Out[3067]: 
0    
1    
Name: all_data, dtype: object
```

**OR**

```
In [3068]: df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r'\\n',''))
Out[3068]: 
  all_data
0         
1
```